# JPA/Hibernate not using all fields in composite primary key

Tags: composite-primary-key

I have a many-to-one relationship as below (I have removed columns that do not contribute to this discussion):

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name = "RecordValue", pkJoinColumns = {
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "RECORD_ID", referencedColumnName = "RECORD_ID") })
Class Record {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "RECORD_ID")
   long recordId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="key")
   Set<RecordValue> values;
}

@Entity
class RecordValue {

   @EmbeddedId
   RecordValuePK pk;

   @Column
   long value;

   @ManyToOne
   @MapsId("recordId")
   private Record key;
}

@Embeddable
class RecordValuePK {
    @Column(name = "RECORD_ID")
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "RECORD_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RECORD"))
    long recordId;

    @Column(name = "COLLECTION_DATE")
    LocalDate collectionDate;
}
```

When hibernate creates tables, the RecordValue table has primary key consisting of only RECORD_ID and NOT COLLECTION_DATE.

What could be the problem?

Hibernate debug log shows the following:

```
DEBUG - Forcing column [collection_date] to be non-null as it is part of the primary key for table [recordvalue]
DEBUG - Forcing column [key_record_id] to be non-null as it is part of the primary key for table [recordvalue]
DEBUG - Forcing column [record_id] to be non-null as it is part of the primary key for table [recordvalue]
```

.
.
Hibernate:

```
create table Record (
    RECORD_ID bigint not null,
    primary key (RECORD_ID)
)
```

Hibernate:

```
create table RecordValue (
   COLLECTION_DATE date not null,
    VALUE bigint not null,
    key_RECORD_ID bigint not null,
    RECORD_ID bigint not null,
    primary key (RECORD_ID)
)
```

Comment: Hibernate did what you've told him to do! you didn't use the  `@EmbeddedId` in the `Record` entity, so why do you expect to get `COLLECTION_DATE` in your id?

Comment: @O.Badr:  Not sure I understand. Why would I need `@EmbeddedId` in Record where the only primary key column is RECORD_ID? I had forgotten to mention the `@SecondaryTable` before, which I have added now.

Comment: It seems like removing the `@SecondaryTable` has resolved this issue. The `@SecondaryTable` was forcing both tables to have the same the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the @SecondaryTable specification has resolved this issue. The @SecondaryTable specification was forcing both tables to have the same the primary key. The found this solution after reading this blog:
 https://antoniogoncalves.org/2008/05/20/primary-and-secondary-table-with-jpa.